# Apache2 reverse proxy and websocks

Tags: apache, websocket, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to allow the websocks in my reverse proxy with this:

```
<Location "/monitor">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/monitor/notify       [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/monitor/notify/(.*) wss://localhost:8001/monitor/notify/$1         [P,L]

        ProxyPass http://localhost:8001/monitor
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8001/monitor
</Location>
```

But I'm getting this error:

`VM690:149 WebSocket connection to 'wss://MY.HOST/monitor/notify/516/q7pqnqdz/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /monitor/(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8001/monitor/$1  [P,L]
```